# Getting an error when accessing the tabbar controller swift

Tags: swift, error-handling

I am using a UITabBarController in my application. I want to access the variables I defined in my tabbar from a child view of one of the tabs :

```
let tabBar = tabBarController as! baseTabBarController
```

I have already done it for an another tab and it works fine. But this time, I am getting an error :

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/ms/Desktop/invoice/invoice/PreviewViewController.swift, line 36
2020-05-30 18:46:26.511904+0200 Invo[9455:2542848] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/ms/Desktop/invoice/invoice/PreviewViewController.swift, line 36
```

Please help ! Thanks.

Here is the view controller class :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webPreview: UIWebView!

    var invoiceComposer: InvoiceComposer!
    var HTMLContent: String!

    var invoiceNumber = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(invoiceNumber)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        createInvoiceAsHTML()
    }

    func createInvoiceAsHTML() {
        invoiceComposer = InvoiceComposer()

        if let tabBar = tabBarController as? baseTabBarController {
            if let invoiceHTML = invoiceComposer.renderInvoice(invoiceNumber: String(invoiceNumber), invoiceDate: "", recipientInfo: tabBar.customerData[invoiceNumber][0].input, items: tabBar.itemsData[invoiceNumber], totalAmount: tabBar.totalData[invoiceNumber].total) {

                   webPreview.loadHTMLString(invoiceHTML, baseURL: NSURL(string: invoiceComposer.pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate!)! as URL)
                   HTMLContent = invoiceHTML
            }
            print("works")
        }
        else {
            print("tabBarController is not of type baseTabBarController or either nil ")
        }

    }

}
```

Here is a view of the storyboard :

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt72E.png)

Here is tabbar controller's implementation :

import UIKit

```
class baseTabBarController: UITabBarController {

     var customerData: [[customerInformation]] = []
     var itemsData: [[Item]] = []
     var totalData: [TotalInformation] = []

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tabBarController is not of type baseTabBarController or either nil 
You can check that

```
if let tabBar = tabBarController as? baseTabBarController {
print("tabBarController exists and of type baseTabBarController")
} else {
print("tabBarController is not of type baseTabBarController or either nil ")
}
```

Comment: If so then why it worked the first time I did the same thing ?

Comment: you can test it .... you just post one line ... replace it with my code .. it will not crash for sure

Comment: Ok I tested it and it seems that you are right. But why is it acting differently in different moment. And how can I access it eventhough ?

Comment: i just know about oe line of code that you posted :) how can i tell you ? please post necessary code .. where you are writing this code

Comment: i have few questions .. you have customerData in tabBar ? `PreviewViewController` is in tabbar ?

Comment: PreviewViewController is a view connected by a show segue to a tab view (tab view --> PreviewViewController)

Comment: try to access it in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewWillAppear`

Comment: can you share demo project ?

Comment: also check if you assign baseTabBarController to tabbar in storyboard

Comment: Yes I did it and here is the demo project : https://github.com/m4thus4n/project (it's my brother's account)

Comment: please update the code ... i am unable to find project

Comment: if you want to. access tabBar you need to push ... instead of present..
here is the link of fixed project 
we.tl/t-cG5pzQd3D9

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the color of the tabBar has changed to gray instead of black for the  first tab. I tried to find out the problem but couldn't... Can you help please ?